# Calcular o faturamento total da loja em Java

Tags: java

Estou com dificuldades para calcular o faturamento total da loja `totalV`, pois não estou sabendo como guardar os valores totais de cada produto `totalProd` sem que um novo produto substitua o anterior.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String produto = "";
    Scanner scanproduto = new Scanner(System.in);
    int quant_produto = 0;
    double totalProd = 0;
    double precoUn = 0;
    double totalV =0;

    System.out.print("CONTROLE DE VENDAS DE UMA LOJA DE ELETRODOMÉSTICOS\n");
    System.out.print("--------------------------------------------\n\n");

    System.out.println(" Digite Fim para terminar o lançamento.");

    while (!produto.equals("Fim") && !produto.equals("FIM")) {

        System.out.print("Digite o nome do produto: ");
        produto = scanproduto.nextLine();

        if (!produto.equals("Fim") && !produto.equals("FIM")) {

            System.out.print("Informe o preço unitario:");
            precoUn = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Informe a quantidade de produtos vendidos:");
            quant_produto = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Produto:" + produto);
            System.out.println("Preço unitário:" + precoUn);
            System.out.println("Quantidade vendida:" + quant_produto);
            totalProd = (quant_produto * precoUn);
            System.out.println("Valor total do produto:" + totalProd);
        } else {
            {

                System.out.println("R$ " + totalV);

                if (totalV <= 10000) {
                    System.out.println("FATURAMENTO BAIXO");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("FATURAMENTO ÓTIMO");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa atribuir o **totalV** com o *Total dos produtos*. Não é necessário colocar outros IF, pois o while só vai ficar em loop até que seja diferente de FIM

Tenta dessa forma:

```
 while (!produto.equals("Fim")) {

        System.out.print("Digite o nome do produto: ");
        produto = scanproduto.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Informe o preço unitario:");
        precoUn = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Informe a quantidade de produtos vendidos:");
        quant_produto = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Produto:" + produto);
        System.out.println("Preço unitário:" + precoUn);
        System.out.println("Quantidade vendida:" + quant_produto);
        totalProd = (quant_produto * precoUn);
        System.out.println("Valor total do produto:" + totalProd);

        // aqui falto somar o total
        totalV = totalV + totalProd;
  }


    System.out.println("R$ " + totalV);

    if (totalV <= 10000) {
        System.out.println("FATURAMENTO BAIXO");
    } else {
        System.out.println("FATURAMENTO ÓTIMO");
    }
```

> Se deseja verificar a forma de digitação de uma palavra, utilize o
>   equalsignorecase("Fim"), não importa se o usuário irá digitar: FIM,
>   FIm, FiM, fim ... que irá funcionar como fim.

Answer (score 0):

Esse código resolver seu problema, criando um lista Maps de produto

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Map<String, double> map = new HashMap<String, double>();
    String produto = "";
    Scanner scanproduto = new Scanner(System.in);
    int quant_produto = 0;
    double precoUn = 0;
    double totalV =0;

    System.out.print("CONTROLE DE VENDAS DE UMA LOJA DE ELETRODOMÉSTICOS\n");
    System.out.print("--------------------------------------------\n\n");

    System.out.println(" Digite Fim para terminar o lançamento.");

    while (!produto.equals("Fim") && !produto.equals("FIM")) {

        System.out.print("Digite o nome do produto: ");
        produto = scanproduto.nextLine();

        if (!produto.equals("Fim") && !produto.equals("FIM")) {

            System.out.print("Informe o preço unitario:");
            precoUn = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Informe a quantidade de produtos vendidos:");
            quant_produto = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Produto:" + produto);
            System.out.println("Preço unitário:" + precoUn);
            System.out.println("Quantidade vendida:" + quant_produto);
            totalProd = (quant_produto * precoUn);
            map.put(produto, totalProd);
            System.out.println("Valor total do " + produto + ":" + map.get(produto));
            totalV = totalV + map.get(produto);
        } else {
            {
                System.out.println("R$ " + totalV);
                if (totalV <= 10000) {
                    System.out.println("FATURAMENTO BAIXO");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("FATURAMENTO ÓTIMO");
                }

                System.out.println("Lista de todos os produtos e preços");

                for(Map.Entry<String, HashMap> entry : selects.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    System.out.println("Produto: " + key + " - R$ " + map.get(key));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```